# The source code of scala swing Table looks strange

Tags: scala, swing

In library scala-swing_2.12:2.0.0, the source code of class `scala.swing.Table`, line 154:

```
def model = peer.getModel()
def model_=(x: TableModel) = {
  peer.setModel(x)
  model.removeTableModelListener(modelListener)
  model.addTableModelListener(modelListener)
}
```

I think it should be:

```
def model = peer.getModel()
def model_=(x: TableModel) = {
  model.removeTableModelListener(modelListener)
  peer.setModel(x)
  model.addTableModelListener(modelListener)
}
```

Is that right?